# Laravel foreach-ing the create method will add only one record

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent

I'm having troubles with my organizations in Laravel framework.

My store method is like this:

```
public function store(ProfileUpdateRequest $request, $id) {
    $organizations = Input::only('organization');

    foreach($organizations as $id) {
        $data = array(
            'organization_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        );

        Organization_User::create($data);
    }
}
```

And the HTML is like this:

`<select class="select-icons" tabindex="-1" name="organization"></select>`

I'm using select2 4.* to get the records of organizations to the field.

```
$('.select-icons').select2({
    multiple: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: "-1",
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/v1/allorganizations',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) {

            var queryParameters = {
                term: params.term
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (organization) {
                    return {
                        text: organization.name,
                        id: organization.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    },
    formatResult: iconFormat,
    minimumResultsForSearch: "-1",
    width: '100%',
    formatSelection: iconFormat,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

The thing is, that no matter how much records I add, it'll add only one record (that one what I chose first). What should I do, I have been struggling since last night. :D

Comment: Change `organization` to `organization[]` in your `<select` element.

Comment: After i did that, I'm getting an error: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit of refactoring to make this a bit more "Laravely"

```
collect($request->only('organization'))->each(function($id, $index) {
    Organization_User::create([
        'organization_id' => $id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);
});
```

In this way, you can loop over the results from the request. We will then instantiate a collection from our `$request->only('organization')`, which will allow us to chain the `->each()` method, returning the `$id` of the organization, and it's position in the array as represented by the `$index`.

We use `auth()` as opposed to `Auth::` in the event that `Auth::` ever changes to something else in the future, at least we can hope that the `auth()` helper doesn't.

Comment: I modified your code a bit, it's `Organization_User` model, not `Organization` and the column is `organization_id`, not `organization`
But sadly, that didn't work also. Now i'm getting error `Call to a member function each() on array`

Comment: @Ventilaator Have a look at the above edit. Should work better for you.